# Can I safely use std::string to assemble binary data into messages?

Tags: c++

I am using a `std::string` to hold binary data read from a socket.
The data consists of messages beginning with a '$' and ending with a '#'. Each message may contain '\0' characters.

I use `std::string::find()` to find the location of the first message and extract it from the string using `std::string::substr()`:

```
class MessageSplitter {
public:
    MessageSplitter() { m_data.reserve(1'000'000); }
    void appendBinaryData(const std::string& binaryData) {
        m_data.append(bytes);
    }
    bool popMessage(std::string& msg) {
        size_t beg_index = m_data.find("$");
        if (beg_index == std::string::npos) {
            return false;
        }
        size_t end_index = m_data.find("#", beg_index);
        if (end_index == std::string::npos) {
            return false;
        }
        size_t count = end_index - beg_index + end.size();
        msg = m_data.substr(beg_index, count);
        m_data = m_data.substr(end_index + end.size());
        return true;
    }
private:
    std::string m_data;
};
```

I read from socket this way (error checking on recv omitted):

```
char buffer[4096];
int ret = ::recv(m_socket, buffer, 4096, 0);
std::string binaryData = std::string(buffer, ret);
```

This approach seems to work fine on Windows.
However is it guaranteed to work on other platforms according to the C++ standard?

Comment: `MessageSplitter` looks fine.  Your code that reads in the binary data might not be safe though as binary representations can change depending on a number of factors

Comment: This seems like an odd layer of obfuscation over the top of a primarily binary protocol. Why bother? Presumably you know the size of the messages coming in (although who knows what `bytes` is in `appendBinaryData`), presumably there's no real need to store the markers, so you know the total amount of data.

Comment: *(Tangential, but to me, `popMessage` means you get a message back.)*

Comment: @DaveNewton: there are different types of messages with different sizes. Also the messages may come in partwise: "$ab", "c#".

Comment: @Andy It's not clear to me how that matters in the end. When data comes in, you have the length. You know if it's the start, middle, or end of a message *(via the sentinals)*. So the binary portion's length is known and can be appended to the message's buffer *(e.g., each message has a length and its data)*. No calculations after-the-fact seem required.

Comment: @DaveNewton: there are many types of messages. I am only interested in a few. Some of those I am not interested in can have variable length.
Also I think the server can already be sending data before I connect to it. I am just one of several clients. When I connect the first data I receive may be the 2nd half of a message: "c#".  So I still have to search for '$' to find where first readable message starts.

Comment: Personally, I would _never_ use `std::string` to store binary data as it violates the principle of least surprise.  What is wrong with `std::vector <std::byte>>`?

Comment: @Andy So if haven't seen a `$` sentinel you know not to do anything w/ the current message. I don't understand the issue w/ variable length--if you're reading data at some point you know the length; why make it a string buffer? You only care about bytes and are **explicitly** treating `\0` in a non-string way. And if messages are guaranteed to not be combined in a single byte stream you only need to check the last character.

Comment: (Even if they **may** be confined a `$` is still findable (assuming it is invalid as part of a message.) I don't see any reason to pretend binary data is a string--there may **be** a reason, but it escapes me, and IMO things would be significantly cleaner, and more clear, if the messages were wrapped up in a meaningful class (which provides other benefits as well). It has to be parsed into something meaningful anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton: thank you for your advice! I have replaced the class above with a new class: MessageParser that splits the bytestream into messages and parses them. Also I am using std::vector<unsigned char> instead of std::string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly safe from a language level.  `std::string` is guaranteed to be able to handle non-printable characters including embedded nul characters just fine.

From a programmer's prospective though it's somewhat unsafe because it's surprising.  When I see `std::string` I generally expect it to be printable text.  It has an `operator<<` for example to make it easy to print to output streams, and I have to remember never to use that.

For the second reason, I would tend to prefer something more explicit.  `std::vector<std::byte>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` or similar.  Something that doesn't *act* like text is much more difficult to accidentally treat as text.

Comment: From the readability of the code I totally agree. Users may take into account that std::string has short string optimization which std::vector will not use. Vectors with not default given length may also take a while to copy data around. This all may be a significant downside using a vector in this case. Maybe a user provided class may be better in all cases?

Comment: @Klaus I really don't think the protocol above often transmits messages that are small enough to use SSO. And I don't really see how a vector can have worse copy performance than a string. Which implementation are we talking about?

Comment: @Klaus The first thing OP's code does is `reserve` a megabyte of space for their data buffer, so short string optimization was clearly not a consideration.

Comment: @MilesBudnek 1MB is fare a way from SSO. Thats a fact :-)